# Select Query with Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I want to call a procedure with some conditions,
This is my code.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `jijo_db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `view_all_user_details_with_limit`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `view_all_user_details_with_limit`(IN StartNo INT,IN EndNo INT, IN OrderVal VARCHAR(10),IN Cond VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN   
SELECT * FROM `tbl_user_details` WHERE  Cond  ORDER BY OrderVal LIMIT StartNo,EndNo;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

procedure call - `CALL view_all_user_details_with_limit(0,10,'',"NAME LIKE '%a%'");`

**but I dont get any result. why ????**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have variable `WHERE`, `LIMIT`, and `ORDER BY` conditions, you will need to create a prepared statement in your stored procedure.

Try something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `jijo_db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `view_all_user_details_with_limit`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `view_all_user_details_with_limit`(IN StartNo INT,IN EndNo INT, IN OrderVal VARCHAR(10),IN Cond VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
   SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `tbl_user_details` WHERE ', Cond);
   IF OrderVal != '' THEN
      SET @q = CONCAT(@q, ' ORDER BY ', OrderVal);
   END IF;
   SET @q = CONCAT(@q, ' LIMIT ', StartNo, ', ', EndNo - StartNo + 1);
   PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
   EXECUTE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: :- Its working, but how to pass multiple conditions like    CALL view_all_user_details_with_limit(0,10,'',"Name LIKE '%i%' or Gender='Male'");

Comment: It should work fine as it is. Are you seeing an error?

Comment: Query: call view_all_user_details_with_limit(0,10,'',"Name LIKE '%i%' or Gender='Male'")

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Mal LIMIT 0, 11' at line 1

Comment: That looks like your condition got truncated (it lost the final `e'` from the end). Do you have a long enough parameter (I have used VARCHAR(50) and in my test version of this which just echos the query I get `SELECT * FROM \`tbl_user_details\` WHERE Name LIKE '%i%' or Gender='Male' LIMIT 0, 11`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be happening in `WHERE Cond`.

A MySQL Stored Procedure won't interpret that string as an expression, but will instead attempt to cast it to a Boolean.

You can see by running `SELECT CAST("NAME LIKE '%a%'" AS UNSIGNED);` that the string will be interpreted as False, and thereby you won't get any results.

I suggest instead that you accept in your Cond variable a string such as `'%a%'` and then update your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_user_details` 
WHERE `NAME` LIKE Cond
ORDER BY OrderVal
LIMIT StartNo, EndNo;
```

Comment: Another note - `EndNo` in your variables is a little confusing, as MySQL accepts in the `LIMIT` clause a Start Number and Slice Length.  So 100,110 will return results 100-209.  If you want a slice of 10 objects from 100-109, you would specify `LIMIT 100, 10`

Comment: but I have more than one search criterias. I want to pass the conditions dyanmically.